# debugger in visual studio2010 debug always entity

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, entity

I am using visual studio 2010. when i debug my solution by put debugger, when it is debugging fields every field it goes to the entity. I never get this type of debugging. it is taking long time..

For Example,

I have page register the fields are Id, name , employerId like that.. I put breakpoint on Id and start debugging.. At first it came Checking Id then come to Name..but now It Checks the Id and goes to entity for Id and check so many times for the single field...

How to change this? Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

F11 will go into the function or method. Try using F10 instead, which will go to the next statement in line.

Comment: any debug mode i use it is going like that only